# Email IMAP mails Fetching

Tags: java, email, imap, outlook-restapi

When I fetch mails from Third party, my requirement is group this mails in in single thread as per the ThreadId.In case of Gmail I am using [GIMAP](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html). It has a method [ThreadId](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/GmailMessage.html#getThrId--) which gives ThreadId. But in case of other Service Providers like Ymail, Outlook I am not getting any API to get ThreadId.

PS: I don't want to use REST API's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't get ThreadID (X-GM-THRID) because it is not default implementation in IMAP. Its an extension item that Google have implemented along with LABELS (X-GM-LABELS) and MSGID (X-GM-MSGID)

You will have to figure out yourself of getting complete email conversation. There are 2 algorithms to do this.
1st approach is by using "in-Reply-to" field. 
2nd approach is a little complex and is based on References.

This [link](https://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) has details on email threading.

Comment: Thanks Darshan. Link is helpfull